# Trying to define a "rect2"-like function on heterogeneous vectors

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I have the following (hopefully non-controversial!) definition of heterogeneous vectors:

```
Require Vectors.Vector.
Import Vector.VectorNotations.

Section hvec.
  Variable A : Type.
  Variable B : A -> Type.

  Inductive t : forall k : nat, Vector.t A k -> Type :=
  | nil : t 0 []
  | cons :
      forall (a : A) (b : B a) (k : nat) (v : Vector.t A k), t k v -> t (S k) (a :: v).

  Local Notation "[! ]" := nil (format "[! ]").
  Local Notation "h :! t" := (cons _ h _ _ t) (at level 60, right associativity).
  Local Notation "[! x ]" := (x :! [! ]).
```

I'd like to define an `eqb` function (assuming there's one for the component types). To define one, I think I need something like a `rect2`. Following on from the Vectors library by analogy, I think its type should be something like this:

```
  Fixpoint rect2
             (P : forall {k : nat} {v : Vector.t A k} (hv0 hv1 : t k v), Type)
             (bas : P nil nil)
             (rect : forall {k : nat} {v : Vector.t A k} {hv0 hv1 : t k v},
                 P hv0 hv1 ->
                 forall (a : A) (b0 b1 : B a), P (b0 :! hv0) (b1 :! hv1))
             {k : nat}
    : forall (v : Vector.t A k) (hv0 hv1 : t k v), P hv0 hv1.
```

The problem is that I can't work out how to get all the dependent types to go through properly. Matching on `k`, then `v` then `hv0` (which seemed like the obvious approach to me) doesn't seem to work. The problem is that you get this far:

```
refine (
    match k with
    | 0 =>
      fun v =>
        match v with
        | [] =>
          fun hv0 hv1 => _
        | _ => tt
        end
    | S k' => _
    end
).
```

but then can't match on `hv0` sensibly. With no return annotation (`match hv0 with ...`), the types look like this:

```
  ...
  v : Vector.t A 0
  hv0, hv1 : t 0 []
  ============================
  P 0 [] hv0 hv1
```

(note the `hv0` in the obligation, not a `nil`). Trying to write return annotations like `match hv0 as hv0' return P 0 [] hv0' hv1 with ...` doesn't help because now the type of `hv0'` has lost the fact that `k` was zero.

I assume there's a clever trick / correct order to write this sort of thing. Could someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the inversion with an involved dependent pattern match as follows:

```
 Fixpoint rect2
             (P : forall {k : nat} {v : Vector.t A k} (hv0 hv1 : t k v), Type)
             (bas : P nil nil)
             (rect : forall {k : nat} {v : Vector.t A k} {hv0 hv1 : t k v},
                 P hv0 hv1 ->
                 forall (a : A) (b0 b1 : B a), P (b0 :! hv0) (b1 :! hv1))
             {k : nat}
    : forall (v : Vector.t A k) (hv0 hv1 : t k v), P hv0 hv1.
 Proof.
   intro v.
   induction v using Vector.t_rect.
   - intros hv0.
     refine (
            (* match on hv0, retaining info on its indices *)
             match hv0 as z in t k l return forall (hv1 : t k l),
                 (* match on the abstracted index l : Vector.t A k *)
                 match l as l' in Vector.t _ k'
                               return forall (hv0 hv1 : t k' l'), Type
                 with
                 (* when l = [] we have our goal *)
                 | [] => P 0 []
                 (* otherwise we create a dummy goal that we can fulfill *)
                 | _ => fun _ _ => unit
                 end z hv1
             with
             | [!] => _ (* Actual goal with hv0 replaced by [!] *)
             | _ => fun _ => tt  (* Dummy goal of type unit *)
             end).
```

Playing a bit with these kinds of pattern matches can teach you how dependent types work (or not) but it quickly becomes tedious. To go further, the [Equations](https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations) library provides some utilities to handle type dependency and in particular to help with this kind of dependent inversions.
Here is a complete solution using Equations:

```
Require Vectors.Vector.
Import Vector.VectorNotations.

From Equations Require Import Equations.

Module VectorInd.
  (* Provided by Equations *)
  Derive Signature NoConfusionHom for Vector.t.
End VectorInd.

Import VectorInd.

Section hvec.
  Variable A : Type.
  Variable B : A -> Type.

  Inductive t : forall k : nat, Vector.t A k -> Type :=
  | nil : t 0 []
  | cons :
      forall (a : A) (b : B a) (k : nat) (v : Vector.t A k), t k v -> t (S k) (a :: v).

  Local Notation "[! ]" := nil (format "[! ]").
  Local Notation "h :! t" := (cons _ h _ _ t) (at level 60, right associativity).
  Local Notation "[! x ]" := (x :! [! ]).

  (* Provided by Equations *)
  Derive Signature NoConfusionHom for t.

 Fixpoint rect2
             (P : forall {k : nat} {v : Vector.t A k} (hv0 hv1 : t k v), Type)
             (bas : P nil nil)
             (rect : forall {k : nat} {v : Vector.t A k} {hv0 hv1 : t k v},
                 P hv0 hv1 ->
                 forall (a : A) (b0 b1 : B a), P (b0 :! hv0) (b1 :! hv1))
             {k : nat}
    : forall (v : Vector.t A k) (hv0 hv1 : t k v), P hv0 hv1.
 Proof.
   intro v.
   induction v using Vector.t_rect.
   all: intros hv0 hv1; depelim hv0; depelim hv1.
   - apply bas.
   - now apply rect, IHv.
 Defined.
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the help. For anyone else (or future me!), the "magical" bit is that matching on the vector also sorts out the natural number index. I didn't understand why this worked until I twigged that `@Vector.cons` is also indexed by the length (which you can make explicit if you use the `@` sign.